# How can I open and close divs when I click on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

So what I want to achieve is that whenever I click one of the divs (which are top on each others) it opens the div and after another click it closes. I know for that I need to use Javascript/jQuery and I found out that I should use addEventListener function. Also, initially each divs are closed and have a certain height.

[Edited]: as @DanOvidiuBoncut asked, I would like to have an accordion, with the suggestion he made. I tried to modified the example codepen he shared, but I couldn't make it work.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="box box_1" id="first"></div>
<div class="box box_2" id="second"></div>
<div class="box box_3" id="third"></div>
<div class="box box_4" id="fourth"></div>
<div class="box box_5" id="fifth"></div>
```

Each div has some text in it.

CSS Code:

```
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
display: block;
//each div has a particular color just to make it easier to distinguish them from each other.
```

But I just started to use javascript and I cannot make it work so far, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  How is it failing?  You tagged the question with jQuery, are you just looking for the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions?

Comment: in css with :focus and tabindex set in html, you could do this ... label and inputs can, for the fun, do the tricks too. demo test on both ideas http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dsvwF  (accordeon)

Comment: Are you looking for an accordion? You can achieve this using only html and css. Change checkbox to radio here http://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf and you could achieve what you want. Good luck!

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut Exactly what you suggested what I am looking for! I changed all checkbox parts to radio, but then it doesn't open any of the tab at all. Did I miss out something?

Comment: Yes, you also had to change the rule in css that was targetin checkboxes to target input[type=radio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$("div").click(function() { $(this).toggle(); });`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ check the tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").click(
   function() { 
     $("div").hide(); 
     $(this).show();
   }
)
```

This will hide all divs and then show the one you just clicked.